# Error generate DES key for session info. Cause: no such provider: CryptixCrypto

Tags: java, maven, encryption, jce, javax.crypto

After upgrade maven project from Java 7 to Java 8 I've got the following error:

`Error generate DES key for session info. Cause: no such provider: CryptixCrypto`

The problem may be resolved by adding the following line to the appropriate place of the code:

```java
Security.addProvider(new CryptixCrypto());
```

Can anyone explain me what happens and what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Seems like you were using an [old provider](http://www.cryptix.org/) which is now obsolete. You might want to stick to standard Java crypto, as there's no more export control (what a great idea that was).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think that adding 'Security.addProvider(new CryptixCrypto());' line is a correct solution in this situation?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't rely on it, but that depends on your project. If you can find places where you're relying on Cryptix and convert them to use the standard JCE, that would be more future-proof and clean.